# Stopping audio from playing to play other audio

Tags: android, audio

[image: Here is a code sample]

of what I'm trying to accomplish, I've also tried an if statement, where I tested, if the mp.isplaying() and did mp.stop but no luck.  this is all within the main class of the project. I do not have anything in the oncreate method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mp;

public void buttonTapped(View view){

    int id = view.getId();
    String ourId = "";
    ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", getPackageName());

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
  //  Log.i("Stuff", viewId);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Comment: You might want to replace the image with formatted code so that potential answerers can start from where you are without having to type anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code within *** *** should get the problem solved.

```
public void buttonTapped(View view){

    int id = view.getId();
    String ourId = "";
    ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", getPackageName());



 ***if(mp!=null){
         mp.release();
         mp=null;
         }***

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
  //  Log.i("Stuff", viewId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In setOnCompletionListener you have released mp , also add mp = null.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-

> try
>   {
>                               MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
>                               mp.setDataSource(birdsUrlList.get(position).getUrl_audio());
>                               mp.prepare();
>                               mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()     {
>                                   @Override
>                                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
>                                       mp.start();
>                                   }
>                               });
>                               mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
>                                   @Override
>                                   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
>                                         mp.stop()
>                                       mp.release();
>                                   }
>                               });
>                               //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
>   Uri.parse(birdsUrlList.get(position).getUrl_video())));
>                           } catch (Exception e) {
>                               e.printStackTrace();
>                           }
>                       }